# Hovering Over Text and popping up an image

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to hover over some text and display an image? Once your mouse is off the text the image goes away?

```
<p>I have a word, when I hover over it, I see an image </p>
```

When you put your mouse over the word "image" it displays "image1.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want functionality to occur by hovering over a piece of text, which isn't wrapped in an element, this becomes a little more complex, but not impossible by any means. The following takes your 'simple' html, and creates `span` tags around the text you want to have `hover` functionality:

```
$('p').each(
    function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        var spanText = text.replace('image','<span class="imgText">image</span>');
        $(this).html(spanText);
    });

$('.imgText').live(
    'mouseenter',
    function(){
        $('<img src="path/to/img.png" />')
            .appendTo($(this));
    });

$('.imgText').live(
    'mouseleave',
    function(){
        $(this).find('img').remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rj7NY/).

Comment: What if the word "image" set a certain image or the text is "anotherImage" then display image 2 can you modify the code with this if condition. I am not too comfortable with jquery yet.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with pure HTML:

```
<a href="#">Hover over me<img src="whatever.gif" /></a>
```

and CSS:

```
a img { display:none; }
a:hover img { display:block; }
```

[**See example!**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkgN/)

Comment: His question is very general, so I wanted to give the most basic solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.yourTextClass').hover(function() {
  // mouseOver function
  $('#yourImg').show();
}, function() {
  // mouseOut function
  $('#yourImg').hide();
});
```

You can also use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` instead of `show` and `hide` if you want some basic animation.

Comment: can you do this with the simple html I have shown. I am not sure what to do with #yourImage?

Comment: $('.yourTextClass') will select all HTML elements with class="yourTextClass", while $('#yourImg') will select any HTML element with id="yourImg". I think you need some basic jQuery knowledgment before going into this. Take a look here http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Hey, to do that what you need to use is the jquery.hover() method.

What you can do is setup a link tag

### Working Example

http://jsfiddle.net/HDhws/

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dLDS9/):

HTML:

```
<p id="text">Foo</p>
<div id="image_to_show" style="display:none"><img src="image1.jpg"/></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#text').mouseenter(function(){
  $('#image_to_show').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $('#image_to_show').fadeOut();
});
```